# How to identify data after they have been through a whitening transformation and K-means clustering, python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am performing a K-means clustering in Python following this: http://glowingpython.blogspot.no/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html tutorial. I have my data, which are length, breadth and height - which I am whitening using:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import whiten
data = whiten(data)
```

After whitening I am doing the k-means clustering, following the tutorial. My question is: how do I identify the data after I have whitened it? Both when it comes to the plot, and when doing further analysis on the data. I want a way of identifying which data comes in which cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the whitening transform *manually*. It's really easy, if you **look at the source code of `vq.whiten`**! No black magic involved, only linear algebra.

Then it's easy to store the *linear transformation* - and it's *reverse* (a multiplication, OMG!). Then you can map back the means to the original data. If you didn't reduce dimensionality afterwards, it is fairly accurate.

Alternatively, just *recompute the means in the original data space*. This is probably more accurate, but can be much more expensive if you have a lot of data points.

Comment: The  OP is using `scipy`/`numpy` and an answer that uses those functions is a oneliner that solves the problem. @user6135700 function is a better answer

Comment: Except that I can name at least two cases where his code fails. Please study `vq.whiten`, as I'm sure they do know how to handle them.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the scipy docs for [kmeans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html#scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans) as an example
then just do the following

```
kmeans(whitened,book)[0] * numpy.std(features, 0)
```